# how to overwrite netwr default file handler keybinding and still use it?

Tags: key-bindings, netrw

I'd like to overwrite `netrw` plugin's default file handler keybinding `gx`
but still be able to use it:

```
" should remap netrw's gx to gX
xnoremap gX gx

" map gx to something else
xmap gx :SomeCommand<cr>
nmap gx :SomeCommand<cr>
```

Above doesn't work, `gX` does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netrw plug-in also defines a couple of `<Plug>` mappings that you can use to define your own mapping to the "browse" feature.

To map `gX` to those, you can use:

```
nmap gX <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
xmap gX <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
```

netrw checks whether there are already keybindings defined to these two `<Plug>` mappings and, if so, it skips setting up the `gx` mappings itself. (It also skips the `gx` mappings if it finds alternative mappings using that sequence were already defined.) So adding these two should be enough to free up `gx` for whatever you'd like.

Comment: sorry, this is not working

Comment: I was able to get it working after adding these two lines `nno <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseX :call netrw#BrowseX(netrw#GX(),netrw#CheckIfRemote(netrw#GX()))<cr>
xno <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis :<c-u>call netrw#BrowseXVis()<cr>
`

Comment: @blackyellow That's odd that you'd have to add those manually, netrw is supposed to add them for you during its startup... I just double checked, by adding the exact two mappings I mentioned in my answer, it worked fine for me, I ended up with the `gX` mapping defined and the `gx` one undefined...

Comment: Ah! It seems the problem is with setting `g:netrw_nogx`, that prevents the `<Plug>` mappings from being defined... I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Ok, fixed now! Please take another look.